# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When running a Scala file that uses the Spark `Dataset` type I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

I find this strange because I have the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
```

Also, in my `build.sbt` I have the following added to `libraryDependencies`:

```
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.2" % "provided",
```

Comment: How are you running this? If you are submitting to a cluster, is it possible that the spark version is not correct there?

Comment: where are you running this? You are excluding the Spark core and sql libraries from your package in your build file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you are executing this standalone you can try removing `provided` from your dependencies. Provided means that you expect the dependencies to already be on the classpath when you run this application. So the Spark dependencies won't be included in your jar if you use `provided`.

Comment: I have a similar problem running on Intellij but the error will not go away even after removing "provided" . The error includes Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset – Gakuo just now   edit

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ 2020.3.2 community edition, go to menu `run` then `edit configurations`. Finally, in `Modify options` select `'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope'`.

Answer (score 9):

Select checkbox 'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope' in Run/Debug Configurations.

[image: image of dropdown & checkbox]

Comment: This worked for me but, curious what it did and why it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your build.sbt file specified that the spark dependencies are provided to the application's classpath, but it wasn't able to locate them. If you're not running on a cluster, then you can try removing the "provided" from your build.sbt, or put the Spark dependencies on your classpath.

Comment: I have a similar problem on Intellij but the error will not go away even after removing "provided" . The error includes  Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset